# File Writing using fopen_s() & fseek() with SEEK_END

Tags: c, io, fopen, fseek

**Situation**

I'm trying to programatically write some code to a file to then be compiled. I need to be able to add code in without replacing the whole file. I have a `}` on the end of the file, which I need to remove to be able to add the next lot of code, after which the `}` is readded.

My code is currently thus:

```
    //Writes from an offset from the end of a file.
    static bool Write(const char *FilePath, const char *Text)
    {
        FILE *f;
        errno_t error;
        int seekerror;
        if (!(error = fopen_s(&f, FilePath, "w")))
        {
            //one byte offset from the end of the file.
            if (!(seekerror = fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END)))
            {
                fwrite(Text, sizeof(char), strlen(Text), f);
                fclose(f);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Issue**

I believe the `w` and `a` flags override the pointer location from `fseek()`? So I don't seem to be able to overwrite the `}` at the end of the file.

**Does anyone know how I'd be able to write from an offset using `SEEK_END`?**

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `"w"` mode for `fopen`, use `"r+"` instead.

`"r"` - Opens a file for reading. The file must exist.

`"w"` - Creates an **empty file** for writing. If a file with the same name already 
exists, **its content is erased** and the file is considered as a new empty file.

`"a"` - Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the 
file. The file is created if it does not exist.

`"r+"` - Opens a file to update both reading and writing. The file must exist.

`"w+"` - Creates an empty file for both reading and writing.

`"a+"` - Opens a file for reading and appending.